# how to build cron expression for hours and minutes

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

i want a cron expression for a schedule which runs for every 2hr 10 min and output am expecting is 
2:00
4:10
6:20
i tried 0 0/2 0/2 * * ? for that and the output was like this
Thursday, November 1, 2012 12:50 PM
Thursday, November 1, 2012 12:52 PM
Thursday, November 1, 2012 12:54 PM
source-http://www.cronmaker.com

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

I too had searched a lot previous to run a cron for every (> 60 ) minutes, but was not able to find any solution.

Best way to implement the solution to your problem, is to write your own script that would check the script's last run which you can handle in any way (check `timestamp`, log the last run somewhere, etc) and would run the required job if only the time conditions are met.

Then put a `cron` to call this wrapper script every 10 mins (in your case), as this would ensure, it would get checked for each of the time you would have expected the original final job to run.

Hope this helps.